# finding max in a array and their counterpart in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array with the same dimension, one for frequency, one for value.

Examples :

```
var value = [20, 40, 10, 80, 16];
var frequency = [10, 16, 25, 31.5, 40];
```

I used the method math.max in this way

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, value);
```

Now I want to find the frequency in the same position of frequency array.

Comment: `frequency[value.indexOf(maxValue)]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are unique.

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, value);
var index =  value.indexOf(maxValue);
var freq = frequency[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in O(n) time you can do as follows. This should be as efficient as a single `Math.max()` function.

```js
var value = [20, 40, 10, 80, 16],
frequency = [10, 16, 25, 31.5, 40],
   result = value.reduce((p,c,i) => c > p.v ? (p.v = c, p.f = frequency[i],p)
                                            : p, {v:-Infinity, f:-Infinity});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, value); //finding max value
var index_freq = value.indexOf("maxValue "); // findind index of that max
var myFrequecy = frequency[index_freq]; //frequecy value for same as in value
```